# Shuffle on matching game is not working. changed the code to make it simpler and things have broken

Tags: javascript, jquery

Still working on my matching game. Haven't been able to get much to work, so I found simpler code (I thought). Now it won't shuffle the cards. I am about ready to throw my computer across the room and never code again.

Here is the code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var app = {
        objects: [1, 2, 3 , 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36],
    init: function() {

    app.cardList();

    app.shuffle();
    },

    cardList: function () {
        const objs = app.objects.slice(0);
        const cardList = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
            const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * objs.length);
            const [num] = objs.splice(index, 1);
            cardList.push(num, num);
        }
    return cardList;
    },

    shuffle: function () {
        var random = 0;
        var temp = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < app.cardList.length; i++) {
            random = Math.round(Math.random() * i);
            tenp = app.cardList[i];
            app.cardList[i] = app.cardList[random];
            app.cardList[random] = temp;
        }
        app.assignCards();
        console.log('Shuffled card array: ' + app.cardList);
    },
    assignCards: function () {
        $('.card').each(function(index) {
            $(this).attr('data-card-value', app.cardList[index]);
        });
        app.clickHandlers();
    },
```

It stepping through the code, the cardList is created but it doesn't seem to go into the shuffle function.

Comment: Sorry for being so over dramatic, I have been working on this since about 12:30 p and I stopped only for dinner. This is due really soon and its part of a group project and I feel like I am letting my group down

Comment: can you create code snippet in fiddle?

Comment: where is your starting point?

Comment: Does this work? https://jsfiddle.net/nkdt4zcq/

Comment: Have an account now, so here is the updated link. https://jsfiddle.net/Dragoness31/nkdt4zcq/1/

Comment: Welcome to coding. Spread the word. ; )

Comment: All the code for this is at the jsFiddle link now if that helps

Comment: Have to ask: can you not go back to the code that worked?

Comment: Nothing has worked, that is the problem

Comment: That code was supposed to make it so I got 18 random numbers out objects array that has 1-36 in it and make sure that I don't get the same number twice. I think it was removing the numbers from the objects array

Comment: Sry i removed my comment. I was asking about thi: `const objs = app.objects.slice(0);`. But this line doesn't actually do anything...

Comment: That was recommended code.

Comment: I'm bowing out after this, but have a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wazz/avo0bdhe/) to see how you can add alerts to the code to see what's going on. If you already know how, ignore this.